# What is the difference between the Vulcan 562 configuration and the Vulcan 5H2 ("Heavy") configuration?

Tags: rockets, ula, vulcan

I was looking up some information about [ULA's Vulcan rocket](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/atlas-v-and-delta-iv-technical-summary.pdf), and noticed something odd. There are two configurations, Vulcan 5H2 and 562 that have the same number of boosters, the same size of tanks, but the Heavy configuration has slightly more performance. What is difference between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Vulcan Centaur Heavy vehicle, flies the upgraded Centaur using RL10CX engines with nozzle extensions.

[image]

Source: https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/vulcancentaur.pdf?sfvrsn=10d7f58f_2

Comment: I've just asked the (potentially naive) question [Why nozzle extensions for ULA's Vulcan; why not make them this long in the first place?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46134/12102)